# Sorting using comparator

Tags: java, list, comparator

I need to sort below list of **Details** class objects with Java 8 Comparator

```
    class Details{
      String name;
      String age;

    }
```

in the order of Details class's names as below preference

1st--starting with Alphabets

2nd--starting with numeric

and 3rd-- starts with special character

Expected Result s/b:
sorted List of Details = sorted based on Details name irrespective of other parameters in the class

```
    "Came"

    "result"

    "Result came"

    "01 Result"

    "02 Result"

    "05 Result"

    "# Came"

    "# Result"
```

```
    Collections.sort(List.o(details1,details2,details3),(d1,d2)->{

    // got stuck here what to include to achieve the sort as per my requirement

    return d1.getName().compareTo(d2.getName());
    });
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is Java 11(Just used var, that's it) code for you:

```
    var a = List.of(details1, details2, details3)
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt((Details d) -> priority(d.getName())).thenComparing(Details::getName))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If priority method is difficult to understand, you can refer @Eklavya's code

```
    private static int priority(String str){
        return Character.isAlphabetic(str.charAt(0))?1:Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0))?2:3;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom priority like this

```
private static int priority(String str){
    if (Character.isAlphabetic(string.charAt(0)))return 1;
    if (Character.isDigit(string.charAt(0)))     return 2;
    return 3;
}
```

Then you can use in the compare function

```
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Project>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Details o1, Details o2) {
        int result = Integer.compare(priority(o1.name), priority(o2.name));
        if (result != 0) return result;
        return o1.name.compareTo(o2.name);
    }
});
```

Using java 8 syntax

```
Collections.sort(list,Comparator.comparingInt(d -> priority(d.getName()))
                                .thenComparing(d-> d.getName()));
```